# impossible to activate wireless adapter with wash

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

When I try to scan for networks with the program wash part of the reaver suite I get this error:

```
# wash -i wlp0s26u1u1
wash: Relink `/lib64/libiw.so.29' with `/lib64/libm.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `floor'
Segmentation fault (core dumped) here
```

I'm using fedora 30; The wireless adaptor Tp-Link TL-WN722N has always worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem with reaver, instead of wash, I have reaver say same exact thing. Solution was to (before you do solution, install dependancies, instructuion bellow)

a) sudo dnf remove reaver
and then,
b) git clone https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x
cd reaver-wps-fork-t6x*
cd src
./configure
make
sudo make install

And it worked just fine!

Now, BEFORE you do that, you will need to install dependancies as well. https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x

In particular it wants libpcap-dev and build-essential
You will 
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
for build-essential
and for libpcap-dev you will search google for libpcap-dev fedora 30 and download proper fedora 30 rpm for your architecture, or try sudo dnf install libpcap-dev (it did not work for me).

After you done with that.

sudo dnf install pixiewps
sudo dnf install aircrack-ng